# What do /deep/ and ::shadow mean in a CSS selector?

Tags: css, html, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

In looking at Polymer, I see the following CSS selector in the *Styles* tab of Chrome 37's developer tools:

[image]

I've also seen a selector with pseudo selector `::shadow`.

So, what do `/deep/` and `::shadow` in a CSS selector mean?

Comment: Related: [What is the ::content pseudo-element and how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622605/what-is-the-content-pseudo-element-and-how-does-it-work) Not suggesting as dupe since, while I believe the answer there is more comprehensive, the Q&A here was posted earlier and the answer is also good.

Answer (score 95):

---

*As Joel H. points out in the comments, Chrome has since deprecated the `/deep/` combinator, and it gives a syntax error in IE.*

---

HTML5 Web Components offer full encapsulation of CSS styles.

This means that:

- styles defined within a component cannot leak out and effect the rest of the page
- styles defined at the page level do not modify the component's own styles

However sometimes you want to have page-level rules to manipulate the presentation of component elements defined within their shadow DOM. In order to do this, you add `/deep/` to the CSS selector.

So in the example shown, `html /deep/ [self-end]` is selecting all elements under the `html` (top level) element that have the `self-end` attribute, including those buried inside web components' shadow DOMs roots.

If you *require* a selected element to live within a shadow root, then you can use the `::shadow` pseudo selector on its parent element.

Consider:

```
<div>
  <span>Outer</span>
  #shadow-root
  <my-component>
    <span>Inner</span>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

The selector `html /deep/ span` will select both `<span>` elements.

The selector `::shadow span` will select only the inner `<span>` element.

Read more about this in the W3C's [CSS Scoping Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-scoping/#selectordef-deep) specification.

Comment: Whats about browser components that actually can by styled via vendor-prefixes like `input::-webkit-slider-thumb`. Could i select this *slider thumb element* like this: `html /deep/ button[offset]` under the assumption it would be an element of type `button` and had the attribute `offset`. (This is just an non-sense example). [Here is an jsfiddle, just using the default css way to select it](http://jsfiddle.net/gunf7vbv/2/)

Comment: @NicoO, interesting. I played a little with your jsfiddle just now (the site was down for me last night when you commented) and I can't seem to get the `::shadow` pseudo-selector to work for the user agent's shadow DOM. Using `/deep/` did work though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. That sounds very interesting. [Here is an updated version of the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gunf7vbv/5/) using `/deep/` to get rid of all `<div>` elements (which the *slider thumb* seems to be). This only working with chrome at the moment. I feel a need for a caniuse.com page for this kind of selector, since it could lead to much more control about elements maybe even for `<input type="checkbox">` and `<select>` *<- speculation only*

Comment: @NicoO doesn't appear to work in chrome anymore... the standard is changed so [>>> is the new /deep/ combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#deep-combinator). and that also does not target the shadow dom.

Comment: Note that around 2015-2016, the /deep/ combinator was deprecated by Chrome. Also, using it in IE will give you a syntax error.

Comment: @JoelH. thanks. That seems important enough to update the post.

Comment: ::shadow is depracated too

Comment: Interesting read: [The New Angular ::ng-deep and the Shadow-Piercing Combinators Drop](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/remove-shadow-piercing