# Use mobile scrollbar in Polymer

Tags: scrollbar, polymer, desktop

I am working in a demo using [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org) and when I access the app using the browser (Google Chrome for Desktop) the scrollbar are very ugly.

I was searching for a alternative scrollbar and found a good example using only CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907848

How can I use this CSS inside my core-scaffold element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to target elements in the shadow DOM, prefix your css with

```
html /deep/
```

so to target all scrollbars on your site (in webkit browsers like Chrome)

```
  html /deep/ {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background:white;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 7.5px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: lightgrey; //fallback
      background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.25);
    }
  }
```

if you just want to target core-scaffold you can use

```
  html /deep/ core-scaffold {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background:white;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 7.5px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: lightgrey; //fallback
      background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.25);
    }
  }
```

or within the style tags of a custom element (to style only that element)

```
  :host {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background:white;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 7.5px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: lightgrey; //fallback
      background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.25);
    }
  }
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609678/what-do-deep-and-shadow-mean-in-a-css-selector) answer covers more on shadow DOM styling

you can also use [core-style](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/#core-style) for polymer elements