# Width and background color of ng bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I need to modify the width of the tooltip box and the background of it too. How can I achieve it? I am using angular2 and ng bootstrap.

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle info-icon-background" [ngbTooltip]="tooltipContent" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
```

I have tried putting the following in my "task-modal.component.css" css file but it does not seem to work. Please help.

```
.tooltip-inner{
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

In my angular component, I specify the css file as:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'task-modal',
  templateUrl: './task-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['task-modal.component.css'],
  providers: [TasksService]
})
```

Comment: Where is `.tooltip-inner`? I do not see this class in the HTML you posted. Also where is your CSS file located? If it is part of your component then it is encapuslated to your component and you would probably need to use `>>>` or `/deep/` for .scss to break encapsulation.

Answer (score 13):

add this in your css file, in your case **task-modal.component.css**,

Angular 2:

```
/deep/ .tooltip-inner {
 width: 400px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Angular 4.3.0

**/deep/** was [deprecated in Angular 4.3.0](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) and ::ng-deep is now preferred,

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
     width: 400px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately ::ng-deep is also deprecated

Comment: in my case, worked for me like this
```::ng-deep .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: red !important;
}```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to style an element that is outside of your component's encapsulation.

**Give this a shot:**

```
:host >>> .tooltip-inner {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**Note:** [The use of /deep/ and >>> in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134355/the-use-of-deep-and-in-angular-2)

`>>>` Appears to be deprecated. Best way is to have a global style sheet for styles that need to break encapsulation.

You can also break the components encapsulation for styling with the following. `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`  However, I personally prefer breaking it on a case by case basis.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'task-modal',
  templateUrl: './task-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['task-modal.component.css'],
  providers: [TasksService],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
});
```

**Documentation**

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Article Link Can't open

Comment: @13hola, Thanks, I think that was probably the wrong link, not sure what I intended to link there. I am thinking I meant to put the angular doc links there instead.

Answer (score 3):

did you make sure to set `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` in the ts file of the component?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'task-modal',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './task-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['task-modal.component.css'],
  providers: [TasksService]
})
```

in the html add a tooltipClass:

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle info-icon-background" tooltipClass="custom-tooltip-class" [ngbTooltip]="tooltipContent" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
```

and in your css styles use the custom class:

```
.custom-tooltip-class .tooltip-inner{
   width: 400px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.custom-tooltip-class .arrow::before {
   border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom class, define it:

```
.my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

and use in tooltip:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbTooltip="Nice class!"
  tooltipClass="my-custom-class">
  Tooltip with custom class
</button>
```

Comment: That doesn't work
You need 
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
on the component