# Specifying style class for nested angular 2 component

Tags: css, angular

Say inside my.component.html

```
<nested-component [class]="nestedClass"></nested-component>
```

Then when I want to use my component, I want to specify both their style classes:

```
<my-component class="my-component-style" nestedClass="nested-component-style"></my-component>
```

The above did not work (i.e. the nested-component did not get assigned the style class .nested-component-style). How would you fix the code above? Other workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Is nested embedding my component or the other way round ? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Its `<my-component><nested-component></nested-component></my-component>`

Comment: @user1589188 I dont understand `<my-component><nested-component></nested-component></my-comp‌​onent>` code. did you directly use this code? . this is not angular way to declare parent child

Comment: @user1589188 In your css file, put /deep/ in front of your class definition like this: /deep/ .nested-component-style and see if it helps as this may be an issue with stylings not being applied on child components.

Comment: @dexter that worked! magic!

Comment: @dexter you are right. Can you answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
/deep/ .nested-component-style
```

or

```
>>> .nested-component-style
```

in the parent component to have it applied to it's children.

Or to be safer, put your .nested-component-style in styles.css in app level to have it globally defined.

Beware of lack of browser support of /deep/ and >>> selectors.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134355/the-use-of-deep-and-in-angular-2).

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. just add a `@Input` variable in your child component just link

```
  @Input() nestedClass = '';
```

Comment: @user1589188 I just paste your code in my project and I see the class like `<h1 class="nested-component-style">Hello</h1>` in my child component html

Comment: Yes it sees the style class name, but for some reason the style classes has a selector appended to them, like "my-component-style[_ngcontent-c5]" and "nested-component-style[_ngcontent-c5]". But <nested-component> is generated with "_ngcontent-c8", note the last digit different, this caused the style class failed to be applied to the nested component.

Answer (score 1):

my.component.html

```
<nested-component class="nestedClass"></nested-component>
```

And inside
my.component.ts

```
@Input() nestedClass: string;
```

and in nexted.component.html

```
<my-component class="my-component-style" [nestedClass]="'nested-component-style'"></my-component>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have, it sees the style class name, but for some reason the style classes has a selector appended to them, like "my-component-style[_ngcontent-c5]" and "nested-component-style[_ngcontent-c5]". But <nested-component> is generated with "_ngcontent-c8", note the last digit different, this caused the style class failed to be applied to the nested component.

Comment: Can you have a look again? I don't think thats what you have though. You have `[class]` while mine is `class` and `[nestedClass]` . These are important.

Comment: Yeah, tried both, same. But @dexter above gave a working solution!

Comment: Ok Cool. Another solution you can try is appending everything as HTML using safeHTML pipe you may have a look @ the answer <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585453/how-to-bind-raw-html-in-angular2">Here</a>