# How to apply css in ng2-completer based on condition?

Tags: angular, ng2-completer

I am using ng2-completer in my angular 2 application. Is there anyway where I can style or apply css the content in completer dropdown based on some condition. I have contents like RED, BLUE, GREEN ....so on. I want the item RED to have red background color and likewise for the other items in dropdown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `class` conditionally as below:

```
[class.classname]="condition == true"
```

or using `ngClass` as below:

```
[ngClass]="{'classname': condition == true}"
```

You can write different class and add them conditionaly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But to set the 'condition'  I need to get the value of the ng2-completer dropdown content and then apply the condition. Lets say I have 3 items in dropdown namely; red, green and blue. How can I access these items during dropdown load and then apply the class using ngClass?

Comment: You have the data before make it dropdown. You can select after get the data from service or something ... You can also get help of `(selected)="selected($event)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the condition to the ng2-completer like:

```
<ng2-completer [ngClass]="{'red': isRedColor()}" ...></ng2-completer>
```

Then force the css to apply by adding a [deep selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134355/the-use-of-deep-and-in-angular-2)

```
host: >>> ng2-completer.red .completer-row { background:red; }
```

And so on for the other colors.