# Trigger hover style from parent to child component Angular2/4

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating a data tree where the child components are just new instances of the parent. When I hover over the folder name in the parent, I show edit and delete buttons. I want that same behavior when my folder is expanded to show the child components, but the hover does not work. I have tried disabling the view encapsulation and also the /deep/ approach in the css file, but I couldn't get either to work. I've also tried binding a css class and then passing it to the new instance, but again that didn't work.

[image: yes buttons]

[image: no buttons]

library-tree.html (parent to Library)

```
<div id="scrollbar-style">
    <div *ngFor="let media of libraries">   
        <library 
                [media]="media">
        </library>          
    </div>      
</div>
```

library.html (child of Library Tree)

```
<h4 class="category-name>{{media.name}}</h4> //hover here

<div class="edit-delete-btns"> //buttons that show on hover at the top level, but not in child Library components
    <button name="media.id" (click)="onCategoryNameEdit()"></button>
    <button name="media.id" (click)="onCategoryDelete(media.id)"></button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="libraryVisible">
    <ul *ngIf="media.category">
        <li *ngFor="let category of media.category">
            <library [media]="category" [ngClass]="libraryCompClass" [libraryCompClass]="libraryComp"></library>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Library.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Media } from '../../../shared/models/media';

export class LibraryComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() libraryCompClass: string;
  @Input() media: Media;

  constructor() {}

 }
```

library.scss

```
.edit-delete-btns {
    display: none;
    z-index: 102;
}

.category-name:hover ~ .edit-delete-btns {
    display: inline-block; //this works in the top level to show the buttons
}

/deep/ div > ul > li > .libraryCompClass > .library > .category-name:hover ~ .edit-delete-btns {
    display: inline-block; //my attempt at chaining classes to reach the deeper elements in the child component
}

.category-name { 
    z-index: 101;
}

.edit-delete-btns:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing a boolean attribute in my nested library component that was preventing the buttons from showing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Angular 4.3 Now Available](https://blog.angular.io/angular-4-3-now-available-8d57b57eb5a8)

> Support for the emulated /deep/ CSS Selector (the Shadow-Piercing
>   descendant combinator aka >>>) has been deprecated to match browser
>   implementations and Chrome’s intent to remove. **::ng-deep** has been
>   added to provide a temporary workaround for developers currently using
>   this feature.

Ironically I saw **/deep/** in an Angular video today for the first time.
So it was very fresh in my mind. I Googled it and linked the author of the video [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609678/what-do-deep-and-shadow-mean-in-a-css-selector) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7002#issuecomment-249334115) asking if it still worked.
He made me aware of the release notes..

[Seems even ::ng-deep is on the way out](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)